# make ruby hashes from unique logic based on different sections in a file

Tags: ruby, file, parsing, hash

I have a large file with "sections" broken up by `***`.  I must create a hash for each section and a new file where each section is written in a new format (I may write multiple files for sections).  Each section requires unique logic to convert into a hash (split by " ", or "\n", or "=", or '/some patter/').
I'm looking for an approach for identifying sections and applying the appropriate logic to convert the section into a hash.  I can write the individual logic pieces, but are they separate methods or classes called based on a patterns?

With the file being large I'm attempting to read, manipulate, and write line by line.  I've seen ways to glob lines between sections but don't particularly care for that type of solution.  I'm a little confused on how to grab lines between sections and apply different bits of logic when appropriate, line by line.

Any direction is appreciated.  Thanks!

Here's SOME of the input file:

```
  *** Summary ***

 Job Name = test   Date created: Mon Jan 14 15:48:33 2013


 *** Analysis Information 
 Steady State is ON
 Turbulent Incompressible Flow is ON 
 Static Temperature Equation is ON
 Mixed Convection is ON

 *** Field Variable Results Summary For Iteration 300


  Var      Mean          at      Max          at      Min
 Vx Vel  +5.71519e+002 1320103 +3.02718e+004 1319857 -2.66582e+004 mm/s
 Vy Vel  +3.40035e+002 158922 +2.79257e+004 1319731 -1.42855e+004 mm/s
 Vz Vel  -7.17959e+002 1318038 +1.62986e+004 1319053 -2.21582e+004 mm/s
 Press  -2.05980e+001  50858 +5.19412e+003  50905 -1.44865e+003 N/m^2
 Temp  +4.60000e+001  10965 +4.60000e+001 315867 +4.60000e+001 C
 TurbK  +1.19616e+006 1319490 +1.44421e+008  10966 +1.81700e-008 mm^2/s^2
 TurbD  +1.71412e+009 1319490 +2.88554e+011 233065 +5.37798e-004 mm^2/s^3
 Scal1  +0.00000e+000  10965 +0.00000e+000 315867 +0.00000e+000  
 PTotl  -5.91285e+000  50858 +5.19412e+003  50905 -1.44865e+003 N/m^2
 EVisc  +2.52037e-004 1320370 +1.14488e-002   2229 +0.00000e+000 g/mm-s
 ECond  +1.05355e-002 1352833 +5.88890e-002   2229 +0.00000e+000 W/mm-K
 Dens  +2.34793e-004  58024 +3.43080e-003 315867 +1.20473e-006 g/mm^3
 Visc  +1.62605e-005  10965 +1.81700e-005   2229 +0.00000e+000 g/mm-s
 Cond  +2.50840e-002   2229 +2.04000e-001 315867 +2.56300e-005 W/mm-K
 SpecH  +1.01202e+000  38432 +1.81000e+000  10249 +1.00500e-003 J/g-K
 Emiss  +8.94911e-001  10965 +1.00000e+000   2229 +0.00000e+000  
 Transmiss  +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000  
 WRough  +0.00000e+000  10965 +0.00000e+000 315867 +0.00000e+000 mm
 SeeBeck  +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000 V/K
 GenT  +1.11977e+003 223286 +1.18027e+005 584515 +3.19558e-013 1/s


*** Openings ***


         *** Outlet 1 ***

  Surface ID = 2329

  Node near Minimum X,Y,Z of opening = 11761

  Minimum X,Y,Z of opening = 369.964000, 11.275438, -98.433898

     Mass Flow Out            = -1.55703 g/s
  Volume Flow Out            = -1.29242e+006 mm^3/s
     Reynolds Number         = 1303.45
     Outlet Bulk Pressure    = -0 N/m^2
     Outlet Bulk Temperature = 46 C
     Outlet Mach Number      = 0.00734951


         *** Outlet 2 ***

  Surface ID = 2332

  Node near Minimum X,Y,Z of opening = 11125

  Minimum X,Y,Z of opening = 369.964000, 73.727289, -114.615876

     Mass Flow Out            = -20.4612 g/s
  Volume Flow Out            = -1.6984e+007 mm^3/s
     Reynolds Number         = 11182.5
     Outlet Bulk Pressure    = -0 N/m^2
     Outlet Bulk Temperature = 46 C
     Outlet Mach Number      = 0.0079087


         *** Outlet 3 ***

  Surface ID = 2335

  Node near Minimum X,Y,Z of opening = 10924

  Minimum X,Y,Z of opening = 369.964000, 164.751344, 40.640056

     Mass Flow Out            = -32.8714 g/s
  Volume Flow Out            = -2.72852e+007 mm^3/s
     Reynolds Number         = 17965
     Outlet Bulk Pressure    = -0 N/m^2
     Outlet Bulk Temperature = 46 C
     Outlet Mach Number      = 0.00750077

*** Fluid Energy Balance Information:
  MdotIn x Cp x (TOut - TIn) =       663.69 Watts
 (Numerical) Energy Out  -  Energy In =      0.36447 Watts
     Heat Transfer from Wall To Fluid =       761.35 Watts
Heat Transfer Due to Sources In Fluid =            0 Watts

*** Solid Energy Balance Information:
 Heat Transfer from Exterior To Solid =            0 Watts
Heat Transfer Due to Sources In Solid =          761 Watts
    Heat Transfer From Fluid To Solid =      -761.31 Watts

*** Sum of Fluid Forces on Walls ***
   ShearX, PressX =        68651         78199   microNewtons
   ShearY, PressY =        39030   6.9349e+006   microNewtons
   ShearZ, PressZ =       -19749  -4.1017e+006   microNewtons

*** Data for internal fans 

Fan Part Id = 16 Fan Name = fname1
Operating Pressure Rise = 0.46945 Inches of Water
Operating FlowRate = 36.0109 CFM

Fan Part Id = 94 Fan Name = fname2
Operating Pressure Rise = 0.309645 Inches of Water
Operating FlowRate = 2.33407 CFM

Fan Part Id = 95 Fan Name = fname3
Operating Pressure Rise = 0.267133 Inches of Water
Operating FlowRate = 8.78264 CFM


*** Analysis Statistics: 

 Input:              461 seconds 
 Analysis:         12686 seconds 
 Output:             179 seconds 
 Total:            13326 seconds
```

So far here is what I have:

```
sum_file = File.new('sum_file.sum', 'r')
sum_file_hashed = File.new('sum_file_hashed', 'w')

inSection = false #flag when in or out of a section?

    while (line = sum_file.gets ) #while reading lines
        case line
        when /\*{3}/ #Found Sections by ***
            inSection = true #in a section
            l = line.gsub('*', '').strip
            sum_file_hashed.puts('Found a section: ' + l ) #write section name
        end

        ### I'm not sure how to introduce specific logic when in a certain type of section ###

    end

sum_file.close
sum_file_hashed.close
```

I'm now attempting something like:

```
while /found section/
  if /match pattern a/
    call parsera
  if /match pattern b/
    call parserb
end

parsera 
while =! /a section/
do stuff
return?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's Enumerable contains [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) which is great for this sort of task, breaking down a file into blocks based on some marker.

```
require 'pp'

blocks = DATA.readlines.map(&:strip).reject{ |l| l == '' }.slice_before(/\A\*{3}/)
pp blocks.to_a

__END__
  *** Summary ***

 Job Name = test   Date created: Mon Jan 14 15:48:33 2013


 *** Analysis Information 
 Steady State is ON
 Turbulent Incompressible Flow is ON 
 Static Temperature Equation is ON
 Mixed Convection is ON

 *** Field Variable Results Summary For Iteration 300


  Var      Mean          at      Max          at      Min
 Vx Vel  +5.71519e+002 1320103 +3.02718e+004 1319857 -2.66582e+004 mm/s
 Vy Vel  +3.40035e+002 158922 +2.79257e+004 1319731 -1.42855e+004 mm/s
 Vz Vel  -7.17959e+002 1318038 +1.62986e+004 1319053 -2.21582e+004 mm/s
 Press  -2.05980e+001  50858 +5.19412e+003  50905 -1.44865e+003 N/m^2
 Temp  +4.60000e+001  10965 +4.60000e+001 315867 +4.60000e+001 C
 TurbK  +1.19616e+006 1319490 +1.44421e+008  10966 +1.81700e-008 mm^2/s^2
 TurbD  +1.71412e+009 1319490 +2.88554e+011 233065 +5.37798e-004 mm^2/s^3
 Scal1  +0.00000e+000  10965 +0.00000e+000 315867 +0.00000e+000  
 PTotl  -5.91285e+000  50858 +5.19412e+003  50905 -1.44865e+003 N/m^2
 EVisc  +2.52037e-004 1320370 +1.14488e-002   2229 +0.00000e+000 g/mm-s
 ECond  +1.05355e-002 1352833 +5.88890e-002   2229 +0.00000e+000 W/mm-K
 Dens  +2.34793e-004  58024 +3.43080e-003 315867 +1.20473e-006 g/mm^3
 Visc  +1.62605e-005  10965 +1.81700e-005   2229 +0.00000e+000 g/mm-s
 Cond  +2.50840e-002   2229 +2.04000e-001 315867 +2.56300e-005 W/mm-K
 SpecH  +1.01202e+000  38432 +1.81000e+000  10249 +1.00500e-003 J/g-K
 Emiss  +8.94911e-001  10965 +1.00000e+000   2229 +0.00000e+000  
 Transmiss  +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000  
 WRough  +0.00000e+000  10965 +0.00000e+000 315867 +0.00000e+000 mm
 SeeBeck  +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000 V/K
 GenT  +1.11977e+003 223286 +1.18027e+005 584515 +3.19558e-013 1/s
```

I shortened the data because there was too much to use for a sample.

Running the code outputs:

```
[["*** Summary ***",
  "Job Name = test   Date created: Mon Jan 14 15:48:33 2013"],
 ["*** Analysis Information",
  "Steady State is ON",
  "Turbulent Incompressible Flow is ON",
  "Static Temperature Equation is ON",
  "Mixed Convection is ON"],
 ["*** Field Variable Results Summary For Iteration 300",
  "Var      Mean          at      Max          at      Min",
  "Vx Vel  +5.71519e+002 1320103 +3.02718e+004 1319857 -2.66582e+004 mm/s",
  "Vy Vel  +3.40035e+002 158922 +2.79257e+004 1319731 -1.42855e+004 mm/s",
  "Vz Vel  -7.17959e+002 1318038 +1.62986e+004 1319053 -2.21582e+004 mm/s",
  "Press  -2.05980e+001  50858 +5.19412e+003  50905 -1.44865e+003 N/m^2",
  "Temp  +4.60000e+001  10965 +4.60000e+001 315867 +4.60000e+001 C",
  "TurbK  +1.19616e+006 1319490 +1.44421e+008  10966 +1.81700e-008 mm^2/s^2",
  "TurbD  +1.71412e+009 1319490 +2.88554e+011 233065 +5.37798e-004 mm^2/s^3",
  "Scal1  +0.00000e+000  10965 +0.00000e+000 315867 +0.00000e+000",
  "PTotl  -5.91285e+000  50858 +5.19412e+003  50905 -1.44865e+003 N/m^2",
  "EVisc  +2.52037e-004 1320370 +1.14488e-002   2229 +0.00000e+000 g/mm-s",
  "ECond  +1.05355e-002 1352833 +5.88890e-002   2229 +0.00000e+000 W/mm-K",
  "Dens  +2.34793e-004  58024 +3.43080e-003 315867 +1.20473e-006 g/mm^3",
  "Visc  +1.62605e-005  10965 +1.81700e-005   2229 +0.00000e+000 g/mm-s",
  "Cond  +2.50840e-002   2229 +2.04000e-001 315867 +2.56300e-005 W/mm-K",
  "SpecH  +1.01202e+000  38432 +1.81000e+000  10249 +1.00500e-003 J/g-K",
  "Emiss  +8.94911e-001  10965 +1.00000e+000   2229 +0.00000e+000",
  "Transmiss  +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000",
  "WRough  +0.00000e+000  10965 +0.00000e+000 315867 +0.00000e+000 mm",
  "SeeBeck  +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000      0 +0.00000e+000 V/K",
  "GenT  +1.11977e+003 223286 +1.18027e+005 584515 +3.19558e-013 1/s"]]
```

The file was converted to an array of arrays. Leading and trailing whitespace, along with new-lines and carriage-returns were stripped, and blank lines were removed.

Processing the file further is done using a loop over the outer array, and a test that looks at the first line of each sub-array to determine what to do with that block. Something like this would be a starting point:

```
hash = {}
blocks.each do |block|
  case block.shift
  when /Summary/
    # process the summary information

  when /Analysis Information/
    # process the analysis information
    hash[:analysis_information] = Hash[block.map{ |r| r.split(/ +is +/) }]

  when /Field Variable Results/
    # process the field variable results

  end
end
```

The idea is that when the code is done, `hash` will contain parsed data in a hash of hashes or hash of arrays, ready for you to write it out. I'd recommend looking at using YAML, because it makes short work of serializing the data to a file.

I'm not going to add more, because the question sounds very much like a homework assignment, plus parsing the lines isn't that hard. Breaking the file into blocks is a bigger task, and that part is done for you already.

Comment: That is beautiful!  You've introduced some new methods (map($:stip), reject,slice_before) I will read up on.  This seems memory intensive (not line by line); hopefully that won't cause any issues.  THANK YOU!

Comment: In your question you say "large" referring to file size, but don't define what that means. "Memory intensive" isn't as big a concern as it used to be since most servers have huge amounts of RAM. Even my development VMs at work have 8GB available, so pulling in multi-GB files isn't as big a concern as it used to be. That said, your task could be written without a hash to aggregate everything, but it would take a lot more code, similar to how a SAX XML parser works.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all lines in the section to an array. If the next section starts or you are at the end of the file, you call your section-specific method with this array as an argument. That way you don't have to deal with the section logic while detecting the sections.

**Edit:**
Not tested, but this should give an idea:

```
def parse_section_name(name)
  name.gsub!(/\*/, '') # remove *'s
  return name.strip # remove whitespace from both sides
end

def call_section_logic(name, lines)
  case name
  when ...
  ...
  else # unknown name
  end
end

section_lines = []
lines = file.readlines + ['***'] # add last section, too
lines.each do |line|
  if line =~ /^\s*\*{3}/ # detect section
    call_section_logic(section_name, section_lines)
    section_name = parse_section_name(line)
    section_lines.clear
  else
    section_lines << line # add line to array
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction... I can add lines in a section to an array, how do I stop telling it to add to array?  line push until ***?

Comment: Added an example, I use `File#readlines` to get all lines instead of using your loop. It should work your way, too. You just have to call call_section_logic again when you have reached the end of the file.

Comment: Very helpful, I need to read up on the readlines vs. each do vs. while line.gets.  Thanks for this.